# Diagnose linux clocksource issue

Tags: linux-kernel

In order to diagnose an issue with clocksource resolution on my [linux embbeded board](http://getchip.com) I need to know which clocksource driver loaded has been loaded from the Linux OS.

Inside the "[LINUX_SOURCES]/drivers/clocksource" there are several modules. How can I know which of them currently handle my system clock source?

The sysfs "/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource" tell me that I am using the "timer" source, but how could I relate it to its module source code?

Thank you!

Comment: `grep -r '"timer"' drivers/clocksource`

Comment: Thank you @CL, but, as I said, there a lot of "timer*c" sources inside that folder. How could I say which is currently used?

Comment: This command does not match file names.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to the grep pattern. I'll going to try it... Thank you again!